# Concatenate gzipped strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gzip

Does Ruby on Rails support concatenation of gzipped strings? Or is this limited by gzip itself?

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to take an arbitrary number of gzipped strings and concatenate those without decompressing.

Comment: And then what?  Where do the concatenated gzip streams go?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [`Zlib::GzipWriter`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html) can write without decompressing.